# Stake EOS and then unstake

Tags: smart-contract, stake, unstake

Is there any documentation on staking or unstaking EOS using smart contracts?

I basically want to provide an escrow service where the seller needs to stake the value of the item and the buyer stakes the price of the item which are then both unstaked and given to the seller after the buyer receives the item.

Does anyone know if something like this can be done in an EOS smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the **system_contract::delegatebw**, you will know that **Stake** is transfer to a third party account and make a record.

If you want do the things you mentioned:

1. have trusted stake account
2. hold the sellerer's value in stake account
3. hold the buyer's price in stake account
4. make an inline transaction to exchange them

Comment: What would the steps be of creating a trusted stake account?

Comment: That depends on participants